# In Visual Studio 2019, the solution folders are not shown in File Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. In a solution, when I add a solution folder (right click > Add > New Solution Folder) I can't see such a folder in the File Explorer.

How can I see the solution folders in the File Explorer?

Comment: You mean Windows Explorer? What is its connection with Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is exactly.  You can view the folder any file within the project solution, within file explorer, with the right click context menu/